# Best way to record VNC session (VLC screencast)?

Tags: 12.04, vlc, remmina, screencast

I know I can record my desktop while running Remmina, but is there an easy way to record a VNC session without having to watch the actual session live on your screen?   Sometimes I need to leave the VNC session for a while to do some other task and I would like to continue to record during that time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can record a vnc session without even opening a VNC client using vnc2flv: http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/vnc2flv/
It does record in flv but there should not be a problem to convert the output to anything else you need.